# Initialize Checkbox Selection based on Array Values DataGrid MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, datagrid

I have a MUI Datagrid with 2 columns, **ID** and **City Name**, there are actually only 3 cities in the table. I have a citizen object like this:

```js
const userMockup = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Citizen 1",
  cities: [1, 2],
  isAlive: true
};
```

The cities array in userMockup represents the cities in which the user lives (with their respective IDs).

I want the rows of the respective cities in which the user lives to be selected when the page loads, I read some DataGrid documentation but with my current code every row gets selected, I need only the rows with id 1 and 2 to be selected, since those are the user cities.

I suspect that something is wrong in the filter part of the selectionModel state.

Here is my code so far, hope you can help me!

[image: Edit initialize-checkbox-selection-based-on-array-values-datagrid-mui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your row filtering logic needs a bit of adjustment. It should be:

```
rows.filter((r) => userMockup.cities.includes(r.id))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This definitely solves my question. I have one more question that I would like to know if you have the answer, if the cities array in userMockup object is like this: cities: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}] instead of an array of number, how can you do the filtering? Since this way, the filtering throws this exception: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: number; }'

Comment: You would have to use either the `userMockup.cities.find` or `userMockup.cities.findIndex` methods instead. Google "Array.find()" and read more on MDN for examples.